# Spring Boot Actuator - Cannot disable /info endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I tried disabling all actuator endpoints for production environment in `application.yml` configuration file:

```
endpoints.enabled: false
```

It works for all endpoints except for /info.
How can I turn off all endpoints for given environment?

**UPDATE:**

Project I am working on is also acting as Eureka client. 
In documentation for Spring Cloud Netflix in section *Status Page and Health Indicator* (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) it says that "Eureka instance default to "/info" and "/health" respectively".

Is there any solution to disable those endpoints?

I was able to disable */health* endpoint with `endpoints.enabled: false`, but not the */info* endpoint.

Comment: Securing the endpoint may be your only option.  Disabling in production seems a strange choice since you are turning off you ability to use actuator.

Comment: I was able to secure /info endpoint with additional web security configuration (which works beside actuator's default security conf). What I don't like is that all actuator endpoints except _/info_ can be secured by actuator configuration i.e. `management.security.enabled: true`. But in order to secure _/info_ endpoint I need to create separate web security configuration only for this endpoint. It seems like I am doing a bit of hack in the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my problem. I enabled only /info and /health endpoints in actuator. And to allow access to /info endpoint only to users with role ADMIN I needed to mix actuator management security and spring security configuration.

So my *application.yml* looks like this:

```js
endpoints.enabled: false

endpoints:
    info.enabled: true
    health.enabled: true

management.security.role: ADMIN
```

And spring security configuration like this (where I needed to change order of *ManagementSecurityConfig* to have higher priority):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

        public AuthenticationSecurity() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
             auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("secret").roles("ADMIN");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2)
    public static class ManagementSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/info/**")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // API security configuration
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample configuration looks suspicious to me. I guess you meant

```
endpoints:
  enabled: true
```

In any case, I just tried to add this to a vanilla Spring Boot app (using `1.3.1` and all endpoints were disabled (as expected).

Comment: I just updated my question. Thing is that also Eureka is used in the project.  Anyway, I need to disable endpoints so I need to set endpoints to false i.e. `endpoints.enabled: false`. Thing is it works for /health endpoint, but not for the /info.