# Why are all my Spring boot actuator endpoints publicly available?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I have Spring Security on my classpath (and verified working for my own REST controllers), yet my Actuator endpoints are all publicly available by default (except for `/shutdown`).

I can disable endpoints as I please (after reading through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399972/spring-boot-actuator-cannot-disable-info-endpoint) question), but enabled ones are always available without authentication and without the role required by `management.security.role` in my properties.

Even when I explicitly set `endpoints.beans.sensitive=true` for instance, it's still accessible without authentication.

My Security configuration which uses LDAP for authentication:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private LdapContextSource contextSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(contextSource)
                .groupRoleAttribute("<hidden>")
                .groupSearchBase("<hidden>")
                .groupSearchFilter("<hidden>")
                .userDnPatterns("<hidden>");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic();
    }
}
```

My application.properties during this test:

```
# Log4J properties
logging.file=${user.home}/nubis-log.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO
logging.register-shutdown-hook=true

# SSL configuration
server.ssl.key-store=<hidden>
server.ssl.key-store-password=<hidden>
server.ssl.keyStoreType=<hidden>
server.ssl.key-password=<hidden>

# Spring actuator
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.info.enabled=true
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.beans.enabled=true
endpoints.beans.sensitive=true
management.security.role=ADMIN
```

My console output:

```
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.742] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.742] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.743] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'CORSFilter' to: [/*]
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.743] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.743] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- ServletRegistrationBean: Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2016-04-15 12:30:05.800] boot - 2754 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] --- DelegatingFilterProxy: Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
[2016-04-15 12:30:07.059] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2016-04-15 12:30:07.061] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2016-04-15 12:30:07.063] boot - 2754  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
```

Could there be a configuration/property blocking Spring Security somewhere? Do I need to configure something extra to make it work with LDAP?

Comment: You probably are misconfiguring Spring Security? Try `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: @XtremeBiker This works but I don't want all requests to be authenticated. This is why I use `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: You are configuring security yourself, hence the security configuration in the `application.properties` doesn't have any effect. You are basically overriding it yourself, and as you haven't protected anything everything is accessible.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me. Is there a way then to use @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity for my rest controllers and http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() for Spring Actuator?

Answer (score -1):

All the endpoints have a sensitive property that needs to be set to `true`

look at Apedenix A https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

search for ACTUATOR PROPERTIES on that page.

Comment: According to [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html), most of the endpoints' sensitivity defaults to true.

Comment: At the time this answer was posted it was not the case.